# Joomla extension EU e-Privacy Directive delete thirdparty session

Tags: php, joomla2.5, session-cookies

I am using the Joomla Extension EU e-Privacy Directive to delete Cookies in a project with Joomla 2.5.4  and inform the user about the Cookies,But it delete the third-party SESSION value.

How to avoid this. is it have any option to manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. ask the developer first (that's me)
2. the session cookie isn't 3rd party - it belongs to Joomla
3. the extension prevents ALL cookies unless the user has authorized them.

Unless you subscribe to the "Implied Consent" opinion of the ICO (which doesn't represent all EU member states), the user must authorize cookies before they can be placed on their computer.  As soon as the user accepts cookies - the session cookie is allowed (along with whatever other cookies the extension may have blocked)